# Повторное открытие файла на чтение

Tags: c++, winapi

Файл открыт на чтение и запись, системное кеширование отключено:

```
::CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,  OPEN_EXISTING,
             FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);
```

Открыт корректно, ему назначен какой-то дескриптор. Что-то туда записали. Файл не закрываем, но знаем, что изменяться он гарантированно не будет. Есть ли возможность открыть повторно этот файл, но уже только на чтение?

Comment: Зачем его повторно открывать, если он уже был открыт на чтение, и, возможно, считан?

Comment: Мне кажется, быстрее попробовать, чем набирать вопрос на SO.

Comment: Один поток написал, но ещё не закрыл, второй поток хочет читать. Сохранить дескриптор и отдать его второму потоку нельзя.

Comment: Ну так откройте ещё один дескриптор во втором потоке, в чём проблема?

Comment: Пробовала переоткрывать файл тоже с помощью CreateFile. Просто так - экспешн. Видимо надо использовать флаг FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED. Но с ним сломался ReadFile.

Comment: `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` это вообще из другой оперы, он не имеет отношения к тому, что вы думаете. Название данного флага весьма неудачно. Кроме того, WinAPI исключений не кидает, и если у Вас там где-то исключение(SEH?), то проблема не в вызове API, а в каких-то параметрах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    //Файл открыт на чтение и запись
    ::CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                 FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, 
                 OPEN_EXISTING, 
                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);

    // второй файл открыт для чтения
    ::CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_READ, 
                 FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                 NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто было посмотреть [описание API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363874(v=vs.85).aspx) и всё становится предельно ясно. Открывайте файл следующим образом:

```
::CreateFile(file_name, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL,  OPEN_EXISTING, 
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, NULL);
```

А затем просто открываете на чтение в другом потоке. Документацию по функции надо читать, там нет ничего сверхестественного.

Comment: Да, сначала так и делала. Повторно вызвать CreateFile не могу - ошибка. GetLastError возвращает код 32 - ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION.

Comment: @sveta_t: А как вы открываете повторно? Тем же кодом?